# Android Lockscreen API?

Tags: api, android-widget, android

I've seen two apps that can customize lockscreens: Widget locker, slidescreen. 
Do we really have an API that lets us customize the lockscreen?

If not, what is the trick?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See mylockforandroid:
[mylockforandroid](http://code.google.com/p/mylockforandroid/)

Its GPL'ed but you will get the code tricks by viewing source.

Comment: I can't find source, can you guide me ?