# Android custom lock screen

Tags: android, android-widget

I want to create an application for custom lock screen,like the one which is in android market with iPhone lock screen UI.I've done some R&D on this but still not getting how would i do this...Please help me...

Comment: Can you post some of your development so far? (as you said you did some Research and Development)

Comment: @SeRPRo---No I haven't started the actual development.But i want to know how do u do that in android?..gathering the information u can say...if you have any idea how to do this please help me...

Comment: I want to know this too!

Comment: just to link some related questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4116001/android-lock-screen-widget http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5529608/android-how-to-develop-custom-lock-screen http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7200976/display-custom-information-on-lock-screen-in-android http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4181615/android-lockscreen-api http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8833270/iphone-like-lock-screen-functionality

Comment: Check out the [Adenda SDK](http://adendamedia.com). You can have your custom lock screen in minutes